# ASP.NET MVC 4 - _Layout Master pages loading in views not configured to do so

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I have created a view (not a partial) that shows only a grid of data for printing. This acts as a print-safe view. This is enabled by a simple  tag that sends you to the view.  The problem is, the master page layouts are being loaded in the view.

Is there anywhere in an ASP.NET MVC 4 app, that could be secretly configuring my views to include the master _layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my _Layout was entirely in 1 element, i was able to use javascript to hide it. This not the answer I like, because its not a solution, it is a cheap work around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. check your `~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` file, you may find something like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

You can override it in your View though:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Or if your View is rendered through an Action, try to return `PartialView()` instead of `View()`:

```
public ActionResult RenderGrid()
{
     ...
     return PartialView(); // return View without invoking _ViewStart.cshtml
}
```

Comment: The second code block, did not change anything. The third block, I was already doing. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `Areas`? is it possible that your have another `_ViewStart.cshtml` in the `Area/Views`?

Comment: No, I am not using Areas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a non-partial view, and unless you override the layout, whatever is configured in `_ViewStart.cshtml` will be used. You can override this by adding this to your view:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```